# Return current URL of a List in itemAdding Event Receiver?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

In an `ItemAdding` Event Receiver I want to return the full URL of the current `List` using c#. How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
string currentURL = SPContext.Current.File.Url;
```

This however returns **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** at runtime.

Basically looking for guidance on what I need to do to return the current URL in this Event Receiver?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error because SPContext.Current is null.Try this instead:

```
string url = properties.Web.Url + "/" + properties.ListItem.Url;
```

> Some note about SPContext.Current - you CAN use SPContext in your
>   EventReceiver, but you must save it in your event receiver's
>   construstor, something like this public MyItemReceiver() { current =
>   SPContext.Current; } and than use this saved context.

Comment: Thanks, that give me the URL to the List but not the List Item.  How would I need to structure the remainder so the URL resolves to the Item?

Comment: i edited my post... please edit the text in your question, because you are asking how to get the URL of the List, not the ListItem

Comment: Some note about SPContext.Current - you CAN use SPContext in your EventReceiver, but you must save it in your event receiver's construstor, something like this `public MyItemReceiver()
        {
            current = SPContext.Current;
        }` and than use this saved context.